# How can i return a ArrayList and a File Array from one method?

Tags: java, file, methods, return

I want to return a ArrayList and a File Array with one method. For more Background(isnt necessary to help me) you can read the rest.

I am coding my version for the Sokoban game. For that i have to get a List(in my case a ArrayList) with all the paths of the levels so i can get the information and I also need the File Array because i used in a previous version and it would take hours to change that. The input for the method is "level" at the moment. Thats the directory with the .xsd files.r

I cant rly change the things i want to return.

```java
public static ArrayList<SokobanLevel> loadLevels(String dirPath) throws SokobanException {
    Path dir = 
        FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(dirPath).toAbsolutePath();
    File[] fileFolder = dir.toFile().listFiles();
    ArrayList<SokobanLevel> allLevel = new ArrayList<SokobanLevel>();
    for(int i = 0; i < fileFolder.length; i++) {
        SokobanLevel sl = new 
                SokobanLevel(fileFolder[i].getAbsolutePath());
        sl.setId(i);
        allLevel.add(sl);
    }
    //would like to also return File[] fileFolder
    return allLevel;
}
```

method works so far so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a tuple like this:

```
Class Result {
   public static final ArrayList list;
   public static final File[] files;
   
   public Result(ArrayList list,File[] files){
       this.list =list;
       this.files = files;
   }
   
}
```

And use it like this:
`return new Result(list,files)`

## When you need to use the list:result.list.

## When you need to use the files:result.files.

---

It's read-only because it's qualifies wiht final keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** return multiple objects from one method. You can put the different objects in an new class and then return that.